# LINQ Query using 3 tables to get grouped data

Tags: linq, dataset

So I am trying to get a list of cities and the name of the best sold product in each city. There are 3 tables and I cant seem to group them properly and get the count.

Here is what I have so far:

```
var result9 = (from p in shop.Tb_Purchases
               join c in shop.Tb_PreferredCustomer on p.Cust_ID equals c.Cust_ID
               join ap in shop.Tb_AvailableProduct on p.Prod_ID equals ap.Prod_ID
               group ap by new { c.City, ap.Name } into g
               select new { City = g.Key.City, Name = g.Key.Name, NumOf = g.Count() }).ToList();
```

and this gives me every product sold in each city and how many of them were sold, however i need only one city and the one product that was sold the most in it.

Comment: Can you join your classes with navigation properties?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to group by just the city and then find each city's best product in a subquery.

```
var result9 = (from p in shop.Tb_Purchases
               join c in shop.Tb_PreferredCustomer on p.Cust_ID equals c.Cust_ID
               join ap in shop.Tb_AvailableProduct on p.Prod_ID equals ap.Prod_ID
               group ap by c.City into g
               let largestProductGroup = g.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
                                          .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count())
                                          .First()
               select new
                      {
                         City = g.Key.City,
                         Name = largestProductGroup.Key.Name,
                         NumOf = largestProductGroup.Count()
                      }).ToList();
```